# Is there a REST API I can use to test a simple client script? Not a test client for a REST API

Tags: asp.net, rest, testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm not looking for a tool to test a REST API, I'm looking to find a REST API that I can send simple GET or POST request to test out a very simple client script that I have. 
So my question would be is there one out there that I can use? I need to collect some data for my report. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific answer from the server or you just want to make a GET/POST and receive whatever response the server sends?

Comment: Hi Emilio, whatever the response the server sends. Just to test out the performance of different libraries that I can use to make HTTP requests, so I have some data (numbers) for my report. Thanks.

Comment: kind of like what this guy did, but he only did HttpClient and RESTSharp: https://amgadfahmi.wordpress.com/2016/03/06/restsharp-vs-httpclient-performance-benchmark/

Comment: Well... since the server does not have to be written in the same language of the client,  maybe this node script helps you: http://pastebin.com/6cvQWPmJ

It returns a JSON if you hit it with a GET, and it returns a text with the POST body you sent to it if you, well, hit it with a POST request.

run it with node, and then make requests to http://127.0.0.1:1337/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots, but REST is a very open world, for instance, technically calling any url via GET is executing a REST service.

If you know which type of service (RESTier,OData...) or what format you would like the response in (XML, JSON...) or even what topic of content you intend on targeting, we can probably provide better examples, but lets start small:

```
GET: bot.whatismyipaddress.com
```

This service simply returns your public IP address in plain text.

If you are interested in JSON responses, try something like: (http://www.jsontest.com)

```
GET: http://ip.jsontest.com/
```

This will return a JSON object similar to this:

```
{"ip": "8.8.8.8"}
```

If you are more interested in testing how you can POST or send a JSON packet to a service, then try something like this: (http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)

```
POST /posts HTTP/1.1
Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 89bda029-e321-f132-1b52-aab9d4b2841f

{ "test":"one" }
```

returns the following:

```
{
  "test": "one",
  "id": 101
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks so much for the response. I think the jsonplaceholder is something i'm looking for. I will try it out and return with an answer.